# How do you increase the number of points pgfplots uses?

Tags: pgfplots, resolution

My plots look blocky.  Is it possible to increase the number of points PGFplots uses when plotting a graph from a formula?

Answer (score 20):

The `samples` axis setting lets you do this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=15,xmin=0,xmax=360,ymin=-1, ymax=1]
  \addplot+[domain=0:360,mark=none] {sin( x )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Looks blocky:

[image]

Upping samples to `samples=65` looks quite a bit smoother for this zoom level:

[image]

Comment: +1. For simple functions like this, you can also add the `smooth` option, then you don't need as many samples. This can introduce unwanted artifacts with more complicated functions, though.